# Crystal Report - Placing decimal point

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting

I'm getting an integer value as 2345 but I want to display it as 234.5

is it possible??

Comment: maybe try to divide it by ten....

Comment: I'm new to crystal reports. how to do that??

Comment: Raju, I believe that what you really want is a decimal mark (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark), not division by 10?

Comment: @Mykolas : yeah.. but how to achieve it in crystal report..

Answer (score 2):

To get what you are looking for in a simple fix is like what kingpin stated above. Divide the value by ten. To do this just create a new formula in crystal by going into your field explorer and right clicking on the formula fields section. Under there should be a option to create a new formula. Then in window that comes up put the field you want to manipulate in the formula and then divide that by ten. And there you go. Now use the formula field in the report instead of the original field.

Here is a example of how it could look.

```
{Table_Foo.value_Bar} / 10
```

Comment: Your formula should look like this: `{some_table.some_value} / 10`

Comment: note that the field must also be changed to a floating point field type otherwise it will just cause further problems

Answer (score 0):

There is a field property for it. Don't have access to crystal reports at the moment, but I know it's there:

> Crystal Report Provides an easy to use default thousand separator for numeric Fields. You can use it by checking Thousand Separator from Field Properties.

If you need a customized separator, check [Customized Thousand Separator in Crystal Report](http://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/customized-thousand-separator-in-crystal-report/).

You also might want to find some tutorials on the Crystal Reports themselves if you still have trouble.